# If there are many clients to the server is it posible the last incremented ID get messed up with another insertion?

Tags: php, mysql

My question is, if this is a busy server and many people are placing orders, meaning inserting to the order table, is it posible, that someone get the last auto-incremented id number from another client, which will mess up the order? (using PHP and MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the PDO functions you can use the function PDO->lastInsertId(); which will return the last id that was inserted by this instance of the PDO class.
Since the other user will use a different instance of this class it is not possible to get the ids mixed up.

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: in case of mysqli it is not possible to secure that?

Comment: PDO is a php class used for certain functions that handle database interactions. Some of these functions replace the mysqli functions.